# dynamically updating the label in c#

Tags: c#

i am using EAGetMail to access the name of the attachments that i am receiving successfully. But on the other hand i want to place that name on the label as shown in the code but my label value is not changing at all.Instead when i click on the other attachment the name of that attachment and the previous attachment combine together and show on label. below is the label code i m using.

```
for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
 {

     att = atts[a];
     MessageBox.Show(""+att.Name);
     label1.Text = att.Name.ToString();
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

     // MessageBox.Show(""+att.Name);

     label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 20);
     label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
     label1.AutoSize = true;
     picture = new PictureBox();
     picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
     picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
     picture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 10);
     picture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
     picture.Image = new Bitmap("C:/Users/HP/source/repos/EmailViewer/EmailViewer/Resources/atts.png");
     panel6.Controls.Add(picture);
     panel6.Controls.Add(label1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to assign the location of label1 everytime in for loop and ForeColor too.

Comment: attName holds the name of the attachment. The problem is with the text of the label. it doesn't change but attName" changes every time i select the new attachment. I hope you understand.

Comment: Have you tried creating new Instance of Label in your for loop.

Comment: i have change that but still not working

Comment: You can call Application.DoEvents() in the end of loop, Might not be the right approach but helps in debugging

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new instance of Label and Picture everytime you are adding them to the container. Otherwise container will always refer to the same object.

so in your for loop,

```
for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
{
 label1=new Label();
   ........Rest of the code.... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can make use of Events:**

- [Microsoft Docs about events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)
- [Raise and consume events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

[Here is an example](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event) of how to use them.
Let me know if you have any trouble implementing this.

Comment: @Taimoor Khalid, have you been able to fix your problem? Have you given a shot with Events or any other solution?